# Prove or disprove: involves Chromatic numbers, and subgraphs isomorphic to Kr

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Prove or Disprove,

a) if a graph $G$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to $K_r$, then the chromatic number is greater than or equal to $r$

b) if the chromatic number is great than or equal to $r$, then $G$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to $K_r$.(converse of a)

would $C_5$ be a counterexample for b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints**:

For a), how many colors would you need to properly color *just* the $K_r$ subgraph?

For b), $C_5$ has chromatic number 3, but does it contain a $K_3$ subgraph?

Comment: a) r colors    b) no it doesnt

Comment: a) is true because for any subgraph of Kr you need at least r colours?

Comment: @user2853442 Not "subgraph *of* $K_r$", but "subgraph that is isomorphic to $K_r$". That is, there are some $r$ vertices of $G$ such that any two of them are connected.

Comment: @user2853442 There is an implicit "for all $r$" in these statements. To find a counterexample, you only need to demonstrate a single graph ($C_5$) and a single $r$ (3) for which the claim fails.

Comment: oh ok got it thank you

Answer (score 1):

If a graph $G$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to $K_r$, then the vertices of this subgraph must be assigned different colors.  Thus, the chromatic number of $G$ is at least $r$.

The converse is not true in general since there exist triangle-free graphs (i.e. graphs without a $K_3$) with arbitrarily large chromatic number.  Methods to construct such graphs have been shown by Tutte (1947) and by Mycielski (1955).  Starting with a triangle-free graph $G_1$, one can construct a sequence of triangle-free graphs $G_2, G_3,\ldots,$ such that the chromatic number of $G_k$ is $k$.